# Map works, but throws a popup error at load complainig about wrong api key

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I see a lot of people have this problem, but none answer I found either here or at stackoverflow.
Problem: Map works super fine! But throws an error at load "This map needs a different api key... sign up at......"
Already signed up, already got a key. On some forum post a guy told that in this case map loads twice, once with the wrong key, another with the right one. But Im sure my app loads it once and with the correct key.

URL: http://ki.org.ua/ (it will redirect to /projects but I think that it aint a problem cuz i tested without redirection too)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in the head you have:

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2.63&amp;key=ABQIAAAAkRXHF1n9aGGQt8LzJ1xJ1hQA4CyG3Bt187CN8-LEMYGKWXG4XhS6rXoQ6mQsghCRL0nVlQKkROWy9A&amp;hl=uk" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

in the middle of the document you have:

```
<script src='http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;key=ABQIAAAAzeIDjGwdGYsF8CGZpljIvRQjXPkxaZ7e_nbTmqIHMenlLusIkxTmBUkmmGWmo0Lm6Gc4B-JEFsGcPQ' type='text/javascript'></script>
```

the key is different, one of those causes the error. simply open the source code of your page, press CTRL+F and type "key" to see this.